# Create Object from JSON with id predefined in Grails

Tags: json, grails

I have a problem! need to get a json object that already with an id already set that is not yet saved. but when trying to create the object id is null. And it is only set when call the save method generating different id's.
ex:

---

`objetoJson = {id: "123413215123", name: "Leonan Teixeira", address: {id: "12345", city: "Victory", state: "Bahia"}}
def person = new Person (objetoJson)`

end state of the object:

Person.id = null
Person.Address = null

---

but I need the id are stored.
the same happens if I do
person.properties = objetoJson

**My classes are mapped with id 'uuid'**

`String id;
static mapping = {
id generator: 'uuid'
}`

**Solution**

add a bindable:true to the constraints

`class MyDomain {
    static constraints = {
        // allow binding of "id" attribute (e.g. in constructor or url parameters)
        id bindable: true
    }
}`

http://www.redcube.de/assigning-id-domain-objects-grails-via-constructor/

Comment: Are you using the Hibernate GORM implementation or something else like Mongo, Redis..?

Comment: I'm using Hibernate GORM!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()

def dataPerson = jsonSlurper.parseText('{ "id":"123456789", "nome": "Leonardo Meurer", "age":"29" }')

def person = new Person (dataPerson)
```

Comment: right, but the id "123456789" is getting null!

the implementation of my classes has the definition for the id

  static mapping = {
         id generator, 'uuid'
     }

Comment: tried here and it did not work, only works when it is defined directly

person.id = 123456789

but need to load from json

Comment: Try setting `static constraints = { id bindable: true }`, non-bindable properties can't be bound automatically. It looks like the `id` property could be non-bindable by default.